# what is the reason for the following equality $\|f\|_{W^{2,s}}=\|(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}f\|_{L^2}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider Sobolev space $W^{2,s}=\{f:\frac {d^k}{dx^k}f \in L^2, \forall k, 0 \leq k\leq s\}$ and take norm $\|f\|_{W^{2,s}}=\sum_{k=0}^s\int_\Omega\frac {d^k}{dx^k}f \frac {d^k}{dx^k}f dx.$What is the reason for the following equality $$\|f\|_{W^{2,s}}=\|(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}f\|_{L^2}?$$

Comment: What norm are you using on $H^s=W^{2,s}$?

Comment: I try the case $s=2$. It seems ture if we can show that $\|\frac{d}{dx}f\|_{L^2}$ can estimate by $\|f\|_{L^2}+\|\frac{d^2}{dx^2}f\|_{L^2}.$

Comment: Then the equality does not hold. However, the two different norms are equivalent. In fact for general $s$ (meaning noninteger), then the equality you wrote is usually the definition.

Comment: When we take which norm this equality holds?

Comment: what about inner product?

Comment: One can define $H^s$ (for any $s\in\mathbb{R}$), as the space of $L^2$ functions $u$ whose Fourier transforms satisfy $(1+\left|\xi\right|^2)^\frac{s}{2}\hat{u} \in L^2$. We can give the space $H^s$ the norm $\|u\|_{H^s}=\|(1-\Delta)^{\frac{s}{2}}u\|_{L^2}$, in which case the Fourier transform is an isometry from $H^s\to L^2\left((1+\left|\xi\right|^2)^\frac{s}{2}d\xi\right) $.

Comment: One can prove that for integer $s$, the above norm is equivalent  to the 'standard' one by considering the 'symbols' $(1+|\xi|^2)^s$ and $\sum_{|\alpha|\le s}|\xi^\alpha|^2$ (note that the Fourier transform turns linear differential operators into polynomials), so that the space $H^s$ as defined above coincides with the one we expect for integer $s$.

Comment: Thank you very much. This idea is much helful.